# How can I use ANTLR to make an interpreter that allows multiple lines?

Tags: antlr

I may just be thinking about this problem the wrong way, but to use ruby as an example, the following works

```
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :004 > a =
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :005 >   1
 => 1
```

However, the following throws an error

```
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :006 > a sdlkfj
NameError: undefined local variable or method `sdlkfj' for #<Object:0x101986e88>
```

This of course seems obvious, but this means there is logic in ruby that is saying "is this line a complete, correct expression, an incomplete (but possibly correct!) expression, or just an expression that can never be complete.

It is easy to use ANTLR to parse scripts at a time, but I am wondering how to best support incremental scripts like this. I imagine one way is to make a grammar whose sole purpose is to validate "incomplete but possible correct expressions" but that seems like it would lead to some serious code duplication...is there a more elegant way within ANTLR to support this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is actually my point. Somehow, ruby knows that a sdlfj is a complete statement, whereas "a =" is _valid_, but not a complete statement. Whether redefining sdlfj changes anything is beside the point. The question is more how does ruby know that "a =" is valid but incomplete, and if this can be done with antlr.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a set of guidelines, but should provide a general idea.

You'll want to make sure the parser rule you're using to parse statements ends with an explicit `EOF`.

```
start : stmt EOF; // good

start : stmt;     // bad! might not parse the whole buffer!
```

1. After any line of input produces a complete statement which gets executed, clear the multiline input "buffer".
2. After a line of data is input from the user, add the data to the buffer, then attempt to parse the entire buffer.

   - If the input buffer is successfully parsed, execute the input (i.e. go to item #1 above).
   - If a syntax error occurs but only after the parser has consumed the `EOF` symbol (either during prediction or matching) from the token stream, the current input is incomplete. Do not execute anything and wait for the user to enter more text.
   - If a syntax error occurs before the parser has consumed the `EOF` symbol, the input contains a syntax error. Report and/or handle the error as you see fit (including probably clear the input buffer without executing anything).

Comment: I think that this is exactly what I was looking for...so is there a different exception that is thrown when you have an outright error, compared to simply an incomplete input? imagine your entire grammar is stmt = A EQUALS B EOF; if you give it a buffer with A EQUALS, how can you tell that you are in an incomplete state?